# Not Able To Display Multiple Things in an Array

Tags: javascript, html

I have made an array that stores what I have inputted into local storage which works like this

```
<form name="myform" action="" method="GET">
   Event Name: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="name" VALUE="" id="input1"><br />
   Event Date and Time: <INPUT TYPE="datetime-local" NAME="date" Value="" id="input2"><br />
   Event Location: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="location" VALUE="" id="input3"><br />
   Event Notes: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="notes" VALUE="" id="input4"><br />
   <button onclick="storeValues(event)" type=submit>Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
function storeValues(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let storedEvents = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Events")) || [];

    const newEventDetails = {
      name: document.getElementById('input1').value,
      dateTime: document.getElementById('input2').value,
      location: document.getElementById('input3').value,
      notes: document.getElementById('input4').value
    }
    storedEvents.push(newEventDetails);
    localStorage.setItem("Events", JSON.stringify(storedEvents));

     console.log('storedEvents', storedEvents);

}
</script>
```

And Currently, I am able to display them like this however it only displays 1 at a time and if I add this code in again but trying to display something else in the array it won't display either.

```
<h2>All Upcoming Events</h2> 
<h2 id='input1'>&nbsp;</h2>
<h2 id='input2'>&nbsp;</h2>
<h2 id='input3'>&nbsp;</h2>
<h2 id='input4'>&nbsp;</h2>

<!-- running script here will populate H2's with values from local storage -->
<script>
   const renderEvent = (event) => {
  document.getElementById('input1').textContent = event.name;
  document.getElementById('input2').textContent = event.dateTime;
  document.getElementById('input3').textContent = event.location;
  document.getElementById('input4').textContent = event.notes;
};
    const index = 0; // for example: display 5th event saved
const storedEvents = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Events"));
if (!storedEvents) throw new Error('No events');
const event = storedEvents[index];
renderEvent(event);

</script>
```

Comment: ID attributes MUST be unique. Are you displaying on same or other page to where these values are stored?

Comment: how would i make it so when I input my ID values be unique

Answer (score 1):

Use a `<ul>` element, and add items to it in a loop.

```
<h2>All upcoming events</h2>
<ul id="events"></ul>
```

```
const storedEvents = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Events"));
var html = '';
storedEvents.forEach({name, dateTime, location, notes}) => {
  html += `<li><h3>${name}</h3><h3>${dateTime}</h3><h3>${location}</h3><h3>${notes}</h3></li>';
});
document.getElementById("events").innerHTML = html;
```

Comment: Hi, so would i implement this on top of my current code?

Comment: Thanks for the help, but when i replace it it doesnt pull anything out of my local storage

Comment: I can't see any reason why it wouldn't pull anything out of local storage. Do you still have the code that stores it?

Comment: Then I can't see why it wouldn't pull it out. That's a separate problem from how to display it.